# Как исправить ошибку при импорте csv файла в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу сделать импорт csv файлов в DB.
Laravel Nova(standalone action) используя Laravel-Excel.
Вот мой импорт:

```
  public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'fname' => $row['fname'],
            'lname' => $row['lname'],
            'mname' => $row['mname'],
            'insurance_number' => $row['insurance_number'],
            'passport' => $row['passport'],
            'tin' => $row['tin'],
            'birthday' => $row['birthday'],
            'country' => $row['country'],
            'state' => $row['state'],
            'city' => $row['city'],
            'address' => $row['address'],
        ]);
    }
```

Делаю все по докам(Laravel-Excel), но на входе получаю вот такой массив dd($row):

```
^ array:2 [
  "idfnamelnamemnameinsurance_numberpassporttinbirthdaycountrystatecityaddresscreated_atupdated_at" => "264;"Katherine";"Witting";"Altenwerth";"13809944975";"7272797335";"964995145319";"1972-05-18";"Algeria";"Montana";"Port Bart";"3017 Jamar Hills Suite 843"
  "" => null
]
```

Как это можно исправить? или так и должно быть и просто я чет не так делаю?(
Ошибка: "Undefined index: fname"

Comment: Видимо у тебя проблема с разделителями

Comment: Но тут большая проблема в постановке вопроса. Как говорится - хорошо заданный вопрос - уже половина ответа. Поэтому постарайся более развернуто задать свой вопрос, чтобы отвечающему не нужно было гадать на кофейной гуще )). Опиши, каким образом парсишь csv, какой пакет используешь, покажи пример своего csv

Comment: Понял что проблема исключительно с CSV, так как скопировав с него данные и закинув в EXCEL, то их спокойно Laravel скушал.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в файле. Если экспортировать из БД Файл CSV или Excel - то согласно докам  Laravel Excel (start 5 min.) съест без проблем.
Но такая проблема возникнет если экспортировать файл CSV для Excel. При попытке съесть такой файл, headingrow будет склеен и вернется массив($row) над которым придется уже проводить доп. манипуляции, скорее всего при помощи форматирования HeadingRow.